# What's the error number for "'The database engine could not lock table"?

Tags: ms-access, error-handling, vba

What's the error number for "The database engine could not lock table..." in Access? I have an intermittent fault that it's hard to reproduce (it only occurs when two people open the database at *exactly* the same time) so I want to build in some error handling, but can't find its error number listed anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like [Error 3211](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb223947%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

You can double-check the message template for that error in the Immediate window:

```
? AccessError(3211)
The database engine could not lock table '|' because it is already in use by another person or process.
```